# Why is this query taking so long to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I wrote this query few months ago. It was running well. But, day by day this query is becoming slower to execute.

This query is checking bill history in multiple tables besides same table execution.

Here is the query -

```
SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT *,                
            (SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = u_bills.UserId) AS username,
            (SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id = u_bills.UserId) AS first_name,
            (SELECT last_name FROM users WHERE id = u_bills.UserId) AS last_name,
            (SELECT phone FROM users WHERE id = u_bills.UserId) AS phone,
            (SELECT email FROM users WHERE id = u_bills.UserId) AS email,
            (SELECT CPRate FROM cpt WHERE UserId = u_bills.UserId ORDER BY AddedDate DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS cprate,
            (SELECT (SELECT PopName FROM pops WHERE PopId = p.PopName) AS PopFullName FROM u_setupinfos AS p 
            WHERE UserId = u_bills.UserId) AS popname,
            (SELECT active FROM users WHERE id = u_bills.UserId) AS active,                
            (SELECT SUM(PaidAmount) AS PaidAmount FROM u_billhistory 
            WHERE UserId = u_bills.UserId AND MONTH(AddedDate) = MONTH(PaidDate)) AS PaidAmount,
            (SELECT PaidDate FROM u_billhistory 
             WHERE UserId = u_bills.UserId AND MONTH(AddedDate) = MONTH(PaidDate) 
             GROUP BY MONTH(PaidDate)) AS PaidDate,
            (SELECT PaymentMedia FROM u_billhistory 
            WHERE UserId = u_bills.UserId AND MONTH(AddedDate) = MONTH(PaidDate) 
            GROUP BY MONTH(PaidDate)) AS PaymentMedia,   
    (SELECT TransactionId FROM u_billhistory 
            WHERE UserId = u_bills.UserId AND MONTH(AddedDate) = MONTH(PaidDate) GROUP BY MONTH(PaidDate)) AS TransactionId,
            (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`BillHisId`,';',`PaidAmount`,';',`PaidDate`) separator '|') AS vals 
FROM u_billhistory 
WHERE UserId = u_bills.UserId 
AND YEAR(PaidDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())) AS TotalPaids
            FROM u_bills) AS m
        WHERE m.username = 'abc'
```

Please check the `EXPLAIN` Report at image-

[image]

I want to organize this query. I need suggestions to make this query faster like 3 to 5 seconds rather than 1 and half minute or more. What mistakes did I make on this query?

Important note-

## I indexed almost each the columns using on the query

Comment: Maybe none - have you updated statistics on the server? How has your data grown over that time?  Are there other DBs competing for resources?

Comment: That said - why all the subqueries to get one field at a time?

Comment: because its gigantic with subquerys

Comment: Separate indexes on individual columns **DO NOT HELP!**

Comment: Among the reasons for its poor performance is that you are filtering on a function result, `YEAR(PaidDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())) `.

Comment: @DanBracuk Can I rewrite that?

Comment: Replace all that with `SELECT username,first_name,.... FROM x JOIN y ON.. JOIN z ON.. ` That way you only hit the tables once instead of a billion times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's slow because you're making it run a separate lookup into an additional table for every field of every record in the results... sometimes more than one. You should use JOINs instead of nested SELECTs. For some of the grouped results, you can join to a `SELECT` statement that does it's own GROUP BY.

---

Additionally, separate indexes on individual columns **DO NOT HELP!!**

Think of indexes like a phone book. A simple phone book uses a *clustered index* on Last Name and First Name. It then also lists the address and phone number for each item. That's what a clustered index is: just the order in which the data is stored.

Additional indexes are like supplements. An non-clustered index on "Phone Number" would be like a supplement at the end of the book that lists phone numbers in order, and then shows the Last Name and First Name (but not the address). An index on "Address" would do the same: a separate supplement that lists addresses in order, and then gives you the name.

With these index supplements, if you have an phone number and want to know the address, you must first lookup the phone number in the supplement in order to find the name, and then lookup the name in the main book to get the address. In this example the phone supplement *does help*, because it's better than a full scan of the phone book.

However, the important thing to notice here is the address supplement _does **not** help this search, even though the address is the exact field you wanted to find. It *may* be useful for other searches, but it does not help in this case. Additionally, keep in mind that every update to your book requires you to update not only the book, but all of the supplements. It's not just storage space, but the time spent updating each index. You need to consider whether it's worth it. If you have a bunch of indexes that are not used, you're better off without them.

---

Getting back to your specific problem, about **the only indexes that will really help you are `u_bills.username`, `user.UserId` (hopefully the cluster for it's table) and a single index for both `u_billhistory.UserId` and `u_billhistory.PaidDate`.**

Here's an initial attempt at refactoring this query:

```
SELECT ub.*, u.username, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.phone, u.email, u.active,
    m.PaidAmount, m.PaymentMedia, m.TransactionId, 
    y.TotalPaids, p.PopName As PopFullName, cpt2.CPRate       

FROM u_bills ub
INNER JOIN users u on u.id = ub.UserId
INNER JOIN u_setupinfos usi on usi.UserId = ub.UserID
INNER JOIN pops p ON p.PopId = usi.PopName
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT UserId, MIN(AddedDate) As cptDate
    FROM cpt
    GROUP BY UserID        
) cpt1 ON cp1.UserID = ub.UserID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT UserID, AddedDate, MIN(CPRate) AS CPRate
    FROM cpt
    GROUP BY UserID, AddedDate
) cpt2 ON cpt2.UserID = ub.UserID AND cpt2.AddedDate = cpt1.ctpDate
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT UserID, MONTH(PaidDate) PaidMonth, SUM(PaidAmount) AS PaidAmount,
        PaymentMedia, TransactionId --these two fields need an aggregate function of some type!
    FROM u_billhistory
    GROUP BY UserId, MONTH(PaidDate)
) m ON m.UserID = ub.UserId AND m.PaidMonth = MONTH(ub.AddedDate)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT UserID, YEAR(PaidDate) As PaidYear, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`BillHisId`,';',`PaidAmount`,';',`PaidDate`) separator '|') AS TotalPaids
    FROM u_billhistory
    WHERE YEAR(PaidDate) = YEAR(CurDate())
    GROUP BY UserId, YEAR(PaidDate)
) y ON Y.UserId = ub.UserId 
WHERE username='abc'
```

Note that it's not quite complete, because we don't have all of the information about your schema and data, and because there was what seemed to be a missing `GROUP BY` and two missing aggregate functions. MySql is bad this way... a better database would not have allowed your query to run until you fixed those things.

Comment: There's a where clause on m.username so an index there would help.

Comment: Was working on it.. the formatting made evaluating some of the other tables take more time.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately, It returns empty. I know it's tough to write a query without schema. If you ask then I can give you the output of my query. Hope that will help. I already tried few other alternatives of your query.

Comment: If any of those joined tables can produce nulls in the output, you may need left join instead of inner join

Comment: @Samrat If this worked for you, I'm curious to learn your before and after execution times.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn current performance is just awesome. You already know the before execution time (1 and half minutes or more). Currently, it's taking maximum 3-5 seconds and sometimes less. If you feel my question is appropriate for the community marked it as a good question. Thanks